\tcolorboxenvironment with parameters
Context
Hi. I am using \tcolorboxenvironment to customize a theorem enviroment created with thmtools (as explained in pages 22 or 400 of the documentation).
This is what I have so far in my preamble:
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}


% Theorem Environment
\declaretheoremstyle[
    % Format
    headformat = {\makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{20pt}}},
    postheadspace = 0pt,
    headpunct =, % \relax
    % Fonts
    headfont = \sffamily\bfseries,
    bodyfont = \normalfont
]{nameAtMargin}

\declaretheorem[style = nameAtMargin, name = Theorem]{theorem}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
    enhanced,
    % Drawing
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    borderline west = {2pt}{-2pt}{Dandelion},
    colback = Dandelion!10!,
    % Spacing
    boxrule = 0pt,
    right = 5pt,
    left = 5pt
}

Problem
Now, I want to declare a colored lemma environment, which is basically the same as the colored theorem environment, except the title would be "Lemma" and the color would be different.
But I don´t want to write almost exactly the same code all over again, because I also want to create a proof environment, definition environment, etc.
The creation of the new environment with thmtools is straighforward since the styling options that don't change were saved in the style nameAtMargin with \declaretheoremstyle:
\declaretheorem[style = nameAtMargin, name = Lemma]{lemma}

But I'm not sure how to do the same for the \tcolorboxenvironment part. I tried "wrapping" the options in a new command \colorboxStyle{} to add the color parameter:
\newcommand{\colorboxStyle}[1]{
    enhanced,
    % Drawing
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    borderline west = {2pt}{-2pt}{#1},
    colback = #1!10!,
    % Spacing
    boxrule = 0pt,
    right = 5pt,
    left = 5pt
}

So I could simply specify the color in \colorboxStyle when declaring a new \tcolorboxenvironment in the preamble:
\tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{
    \colorboxStyle{Cerulean}
}

but it throws an error that says Package pdfkeys: I don't know the key '/tcb/enhanced, frame hidden ... and in the ... continues writing the whole contents of \colorboxStyle{Cerulean}. Seems to me that it takes the contents of the command as just one key.
This is just for the color. I would also like to change fonts, for example, and then I would use two parameters.
Question
How can I add parameters when creating a \tcolorboxenvironment?

use \newtcbtheorem to directly define your theorems as tcolorboxes?

You just need to expand the argument once. You can do this with \ExpandArgs{no}. The n says to leave the first argument of \tcolorboxenvironment alone, and the o says expand the second argument once.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcommand{\colorboxStyle}[1]{
    enhanced,
    % Drawing
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    borderline west = {2pt}{-2pt}{#1},
    colback = #1!10!,
    % Spacing
    boxrule = 0pt,
    right = 5pt,
    left = 5pt
}

% Theorem Environment
\declaretheoremstyle[
    % Format
    headformat = {\makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{20pt}}},
    postheadspace = 0pt,
    headpunct =, % \relax
    % Fonts
    headfont = \sffamily\bfseries,
    bodyfont = \normalfont
]{nameAtMargin}

\declaretheorem[style = nameAtMargin, name = Theorem]{theorem}
\ExpandArgs{no}\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{\colorboxStyle{Dandelion}}

\declaretheorem[style = nameAtMargin, name = Lemma]{lemma}
\ExpandArgs{no}\tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{\colorboxStyle{Cerulean}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
bla bla
\end{lemma}

\end{document}



Define your own specialized command and a suitable style.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcommand{\tcbcolorize}[2]{\tcolorboxenvironment{#1}{nameatmargin=#2}}
\tcbset{
  nameatmargin/.style={
    enhanced,
    % Drawing
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    borderline west = {2pt}{-2pt}{#1},
    colback = #1!10!,
    % Spacing
    boxrule = 0pt,
    right = 5pt,
    left = 5pt
  },
}

% Theorem Environment
\declaretheoremstyle[
    % Format
    headformat = {\makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{20pt}}},
    postheadspace = 0pt,
    headpunct =, % \relax
    % Fonts
    headfont = \sffamily\bfseries,
    bodyfont = \normalfont
]{nameAtMargin}

\declaretheorem[style = nameAtMargin, name = Theorem]{theorem}
\tcbcolorize{theorem}{Dandelion}

\declaretheorem[style = nameAtMargin, name = Lemma]{lemma}
\tcbcolorize{lemma}{Cerulean}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Something needed before the main theorem.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Unicorns exist.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Existing unicorns exist by definition.
\end{proof}

\end{document}


